# How to display all of the tokens in connected wallet?

Tags: wallet

Looking for a way to display the tokens (and values if possible) in a connected wallet using serialization or any other method. Really scratching my head on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Which wallet are you using?

Comment: Whatever wallet works? I just need the code to display tokens and ill make it work in my script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Koios - Account Assets](https://api.koios.rest/#post-/account_assets) API endpoint for this.